# How to center a view in a ConstraintLayout without overlapping uneven neighbours

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm using a custom layout for my title bar, based on a `ConstraintLayout`. I need to center the title text without overlapping the buttons on either side. Currently I've got the title centered between the side buttons, but as they're different widths the title is not centered within the parent view.

This is what it currently looks like (centered between the two buttons rather than centered in the parent):

[image: Current title bar layout]

Is there any way to center the title within the parent, while ensuring it doesn't overlap the button text on either side (as this can change)?

To make it more complicated, I'd also like it to be the title that gets compressed instead of the button text if there isn't space for both to be displayed in full.

If I constrain both edges of my title to the parent and set it to wrap width then it almost works, until the button text gets a bit long.

Comment: Not what any of us want, but I have a programmatic solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63854933/1361689

Answer (score 3):

You should start from Center, then go left & right.

Try below solution, it should work as expected

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_at_the_start"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Awards"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_in_the_middle"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_in_the_middle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="Nominations"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibtn_at_the_end"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_in_the_middle"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.2" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write a comprehensive example! Will this work if the button/title text get longer though?

Comment: Yes, it will get truncated if title is longer than 2 lines. Title maxLines you can change as per your requirement.

Comment: Percents work great. To achieve `wrap_content` width i also added  `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` and `app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"`

Answer (score 1):

To center the view you can give layout_width = "0dp" while connecting two sides of the view to other views. Then the center view takes the place as much as left for the view

**Update**

If you want to center inside parent then, *others view* would be your parent.

```
android:layout_width = "0dp"
android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
android:ellipsize = "end"
android:maxLines = "1"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf = "parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf = "parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf = "parent"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toOf = "parent"
```

Comment: That's how to center it between 2 views yes, but I'm trying to center in the parent

Comment: @Jasurbek That works for centering in the parent, but then it can overlap the button text if either gets too long. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: That is why to centering in the parent there must not have other views on two sides of the view. In your case, just place the TextView center between two views, then align text in the center would solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

you can use

1. **app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf**
2. **app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf**

as shown below

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/nomination" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/someId1" 
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/someId2" 
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/awards" 
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I align start to start of the awards button then it doesn't prevent an overlap if the text is long

Comment: you can use app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="2" to give some weigth for the view

Comment: The OS throws an exception when I use this on something that's not a layout guide